# How does json.Unmarshal() work and how is it stored in a variable?

Tags: json, pointers, go, unmarshalling

Just started with Go and I have a small doubt from a tutorial I am following. I read that `Unmarshall` is some kind of JSON encoding, my doubt here is: `err = json.Unmarshal(body, &p)` why are we assigning the encoded body to `err` and how is `p.Stuff.Fruit` getting the value when I can't see anything assigned to `p`.

**Note : produce is different package which contains some type and arrays.***

```
func main() {
  url := "http://localhost:12337"
  res, err := http.Get(url)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  defer res.Body.Close()

  body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  var p produce.Payload

  err = json.Unmarshal(body, &p)  // I cant get this
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  // how are these getting the values assigned to them

  fmt.Println(p.Stuff.Fruit)
  fmt.Println(p.Stuff.Veggies)
}
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: Read the package documentation. Always, even when following some random tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my doubt here is: `err = json.Unmarshal(body, &p)` why are we assigning the encoded body to `err`

You don't. You pass the `body` to the [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) function, and you assign its *return value* to the `err` variable, which tells you if unmarshaling failed (or succeeded if `err` is `nil`).

> how is `p.Stuff.Fruit` getting the value when I can't see anything assigned to `p`

You pass the address of `p` to `json.Unmarshal()`, so it has a pointer to your variable, and so if it modifies the *pointed* value (pointed by the pointer), it modifies the same value you have (`p`).

See this simple example:

```
func change(p *int) {
    *p = 3
}

func main() {
    var i int
    fmt.Println("Before", i)
    change(&i)
    fmt.Println("After", i)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HNiq7kJkkX7)):

```
Before 0
After 3
```

In the `main()` function we don't assign anything to the local variable `i`, but we pass its address to the `change()` function, which modifies the *pointed* value, and so if we print the value of `i` after the `change()` call, we see its value changed.

You pass the address of `p` to `json.Unmarshal()`, so it will be capable of modifying the value stored in `p`. Under the hood, the [`json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package uses reflection (package [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)) to discover the runtime type of `p` and modify it according to the JSON document you pass to it to parse.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a pointer to payload using `&p` address operator. Now It saves the value at an address pointed by p. According to Golang spec [Unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) takes data in bytes format and interface{} to wrap the variable storing the data at an address.

> Unmarshal parses the JSON-encoded data and stores the result in the
>   value pointed to by v. If v is nil or not a pointer, Unmarshal returns
>   an InvalidUnmarshalError.

Unmarshal function returns an error

```
func Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error

var m Message
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &m)
```

which is why it is assigned to a variable. You can surpass it using `_` operator but it is not a good approach

```
_ := json.Unmarshal(b, &m)
```